# FireBase Query. DataSnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need help on getting the "message" Object from this DataSnapshot result

```
DataSnapshot { key = user-4, value = {-JvFuwKX7r7o0ThXc0x8={sender=unit_owner, message=fkfkgkgkgkggkgkgkgkgkgkgkgkgkgkgkgkglgkgkgkgkgkgkgkg, role=unit_owner, profile_image=http://54.169.41.20/assets/boy-862a2e9036b094973c04afa1c0365a45.png, name=Paul Bartbartbart}} }
```

I am able to get the key value by `getKey()` and I have `JvFuwKX7r7o0ThXc0x8` as an Object as well, this is an automatic FireBase generated name of the object. Instead of listening to the object itself. How can I navigate trough, "sender" or "message" and getting its value by using DataSnapshot member methods?

Comment: Can you share the JSON that you store in Firebase and the code that you use to retrieve it? I'm having a hard time parsing the Android output of it. I think I see the structure, but just want to make sure before typing an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like you're adding a value listener to something that has multiple children. I'm guessing it's a `limitToLast(1)` query, but it would be really helpful if you include the code in your question. Until you do add it however, this is my guess of what your code looks like:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
Query messages = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
messages.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Messages", dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
})
```

While you are limiting the filter to single message, you are still a **list** of messages. It's just a list of only 1 message.

This means that on `onDataChange` you will still need to drill down into the child. Since you cannot do that by index, you will need to use a `for` loop:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String message = (String) chatSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
        String sender = (String) chatSnapshot.child("sender").getValue();
    }
}
```

Note that this gets a lot more readable if you take a moment to create a Java class that represents the message:

```
public class Chat {
    String message;
    String sender;
    public String getMessage() { return message; }
    public String getSender() { return sender; }
}
```

Then you can get the message with:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Chat chat = chatSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        String message = chat.getMessage();
        String sender = chat.getSender();
    }
}
```

The above snippet still needs the `for` loop, since you're still getting a list of 1 messages. If you want to get rid of that loop, you can register a child event listener:

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        String message = chat.getMessage();
        String sender = chat.getSender();
    }

    // other overridden messages have been removed for brevity

})
```

Firebase will call the `onChildAdded()` method for each child, so you don't have to look over them yourself.

Comment: This is the Best answer Detailed and clear. From all the queries I have seen in FireBase Tag. The only thing missing here is the List Approach. Which I actually use from your example Class. BTW the Class getValue Example that I tried, is sending me an error Bounce Type. So what I did to fix it is, put Static on my Class. I HAVE NO IDEA WHY IT WORKED.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds interesting, I've never had to make the class static, but I never use inner classes for these anyway. Can you open a new question for that debouncing problem? Post the JSON, you Java class and the code how you read it.

Comment: Sure, I will add that question. For later. For Now I am having a problem Trying to stop getting all of the collection, FireBase on Fire will throw me all of the Collection. 

Is it something to do with putting the Chat Class inside a Service? (Not an Intent Service). What I did is, I added the Chat Class where my Service Class is, and the FireBase Listeners are also in there. I will have to open up a Question about this, because I am not sure what might happen in the future.

Comment: I can't say from your description. Post a question with a minimal-but-complete repro of the problem and I'll have a look. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Incredibly enough somebody else today reached out with the same problem with an inner class. The reason is clear btw. A non-static inner class has an implicit reference to its containing class. And that's a field that Firebase cannot initialize for you when it deserializes. In other words: "bla bla bla... it must be static". :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Make sense now. I wonder why did it came into my Mind that I had to put Static on it. Lol, I guess I got into the position to try everything that doesn't even make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The value will be returned as an `Object`, as you've stated, but you can actually cast it to `Map<String, Object>` since you know it should be a map.

So, do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> val = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String message = (String) val.get("message");
String sender = (String) val.get("sender");
```